# SCSS (sass) calculation: #{}

Tags: css, sass

i'm quite confused at the moment when it comes to calculating a font-size

this is the normal calculation I already use.

`font-size: #{($font-size*0.7) / $em}em`

What I wanna do now is divide an entire statement like the one above with another one … sounds complicated I know.

So I have `#{($font-size*0.7) / $em}`
And I have `#{($font-size*0.8125) / $em}`

I want to devide those two values now …

So `font-size: #{($font-size*0.7) / $em} / #{($font-size*0.8125) / $em}em`.

But that doesn't work. Any idea how I do a calculation like that with SASS?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try:

```
font-size: #{(($font-size*0.7) / $em) / (($font-size*0.8125) / $em)}em
```

The interpolation back into a string `#{...}` should be the last thing done after the calculations.

Answer (score 9):

ScottS answer appears to be *technically* correct, but why do you even need such a complex expression in the first place? Expressed as a fraction, this can be simplified to

```
($font-size * 0.7 / $em) / ($font-size * 0.8125 / $em) = 0.7 / 0.8125
```

And your final expression would be

```
font-size: #{(0.7/0.8125)}em
```

...wouldn't it?

Comment: +1 for an excellent point. I totally missed the fact that the order of operations and values used here allowed it to reduce. Indeed, even your answer could probably be practically reduced further to something like: `font-size: 0.86153em` (or whatever rounding one wanted), having the fraction already precalculated, which takes out both the division and need to do the interpolation back to a string.

Comment: @ScottS: you're right, I've just assumed that the decimal fractions would end up being replaced by variables