# SASS using % sign to specify width

Tags: css, sass

I wanted some dynamic with according to grid size. Below is the code I am trying:

```
$grid-elements: 1 2 3 4 5 6;
@each $grids in $grid-elements {
  .display-grids-#{$grids} {
    width: (100/#{$grids})%;
  }
}
```

which should behave like:
suppose 2 have two column structure

```
<div>
  <div class="display-grids-2"></div>
  <div class="display-grids-2"></div>
</div>
```

then CSS should be like

```
.display-grids-2 {
  width: 50%;
}
```

Here, `(100/#{$grids})%;` this expression is having problem.
Can not use `%` and `;` sign together.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SCSS (sass) calculation: #{}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783451/scss-sass-calculation)

Answer (score 1):

Just write `width: 100% / $grids;`

```
$grid-elements: 1 2 3 4 5 6;

@each $grids in $grid-elements {
  .display-grids-#{$grids} {
    width: 100% / $grids;
  }
}
```

Sassmeister [demo](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/7f5c11351c980f5d68f7b1f14cbdd245).